# Cleaner/simpler way of writing this jquery "if" code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Ive written this if statement and it works fine but was just wondering if theres an easier/simpler way of doing it

```
if(id == 'small'){
    $('#box').append('<div class="small">' + foo + '</div>');
    $('.medium,.large').remove();
}
if(id == 'medium'){
    $('#box').append('<div class="medium">' + foo + '</div>');
    $('.small,.large').remove();
}
if(id == 'large'){
    $('#box').append('<div class="large">' + foo + '</div>');
    $('.small,.medium').remove();
}
```

Comment: Will `.small`, `.medium` and `.large` only ever be children of `#box`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest something like:

```
if (id == 'small' || id == 'medium' || id == 'large') {

    $('#box').append('<div class="' id '">' + foo + '</div>');
    $('.small, .medium, .large').not('.' + id).remove();

}
```

Though I suspect it could be improved, and this is, as yet, untested.

Revised example:

```
$('ul li').click(

function() {
    var ID = this.id;

    if (ID == 'small' || ID == 'medium' || ID == 'large') {

        $('<div />').addClass(ID).appendTo('#box');
        $('#box .small, #box .medium, #box .large')
            .not('.' + ID + ':first')
            .remove();

    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mQxZt/2/).

The above demonstration revised by the addition of `+ ':first'` in the `.not()` method, in order to prevent duplicate boxes of the same class being added, as noted as a problem in the comments from @Dizzi:

> This works but if you click more then once youget additional boxes.

---

**Edited** to revise a little further:

```
$('ul li').click(

function() {
    var ID = this.id;
    var foo = "some content, from somewhere.";

    if (ID == 'small' || ID == 'medium' || ID == 'large') {

        $('#box')
            .empty();

        $('<div />')
            .addClass(ID)
            .text(foo)
            .appendTo('#box');

    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mQxZt/1/).

The use of `empty()` only works if the `.small`, `.medium` and `.large` divs are the *only* contents of `#box`. If they are, it's slightly faster to empty the `#box` and *then* insert into it, rather than first inserting and *then* using a selector to remove the other contents.

If there are other contents, then the selector will (probably) still have to be used in place of `empty()`, though.

---

**Edited** to include the suggestion from @Raynos (in comments):

> `if (ID in {small:0, medium:0, large:0})` works aswell but is less readable. It's less characters though!

```
$('ul li').click(

function() {
    var ID = this.id;
    var foo = "some content, from somewhere.";

    if (ID in {small:0, medium:0, large:0}) {

        $('#box')
            .empty();

        $('<div />')
            .addClass(ID)
            .text(foo)
            .appendTo('#box');

    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mQxZt/3/).

References:

- [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: First revised works but if you click more then once you get additional boxes but second revision you don't

Comment: Yeah, that's a flaw in the second (and first) suggestions. Removed and improved in the final version...which, of course, is the one I recommend... =) (also, see the edited second example which removes the problem.)

Comment: Thanks very much David "Edited to revise a little further:" works perfect I just had to change .text() to .html()

Comment: `if (ID in {small:0, medium:0, large:0})` works aswell but is less readable. It's less characters though!

Comment: @Raynos: thanks! That's superb, and I'd not even considered doing it that way; have a hearty **+1** =D

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like:

```
$('#box').append('<div class="'+id+'">' + foo + '</div>');
$('.small,.medium,.large').not('.'+id).remove();
```

probably not the best way, but it cuts it to 2 lines.  I would imagine though if I had a better understanding of the overall code, you could probably do this in a better way.  It seems like this is probably called multiple times, adding and removing divs each time is not optimal.

At the very least, you should use if/else instead of separate ifs or a [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: Why suggest something you shouldn't do on a serious (non-codegolf) question? Especially if the asker seems to be a bit of a beginner.

Comment: @nightcracker, I dont' know the full context of his application.  If this is only called once to modify an already existing page which he does not have access to modify on the backend (assuming not) then it's not that bad.  And regardless, it's still educational to understand how what he had written can be written better.  You'll notice the accepted solution did the same thing, answered the question but then suggested that the whole thing be changed (although obviously in more detail).